# Unexpected text "foo" when building .jar file with ant

Tags: java, xml, ant

I am trying to convert [JNEAT](http://nn.cs.utexas.edu/?neat-java) into a `.jar` file, using [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) (and following [these instructions](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/desktopdev/suntech/java/integrating-jneat-into-a-custom-simulati/)). My `build.xml` file looks as follows:

```
<project name="jneat" default="jar" basedir=".">
  <property name="src" value="."/>
 
  <target name="compile">
    <javac srcdir="${src}"/>
  </target>
 
  <target name="compile-debug">
    <javac debug="on" srcdir="${src}"/>
  </target>
 
  <target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <jar jarfile="jneat.jar" basedir="${src}">
       <include name="gui/*.class"/>
       <include name="jneat/*.class"/>
       <include name="jNeatCommon/*.class"/>
       <include name="log/*.class"/>
    </jar>
  </target>
</project>
```

When executing

```
ant
```

from the root directory, I get the following error:

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\jes\build.xml:2: Unexpected text "á"
```

Answer (score 0):

i was able to make it work by removing the indentation:

```
<project name="jneat" default="jar" basedir=".">
<property name="src" value="."/>
<target name="compile">
<javac srcdir="${src}"/>
</target>
<target name="compile-debug">
<javac debug="on" srcdir="${src}"/>
</target>
<target name="jar" depends="compile">
<jar jarfile="jneat.jar" basedir="${src}">
<include name="gui/*.class"/>
<include name="jneat/*.class"/>
<include name="jNeatCommon/*.class"/>
<include name="log/*.class"/>
</jar>
</target>
</project>
```

Is this always required for Apache Ant?

Comment: No, Ant uses standard XML. Indentation has no effect. Your original build script contained text outside of an expected location on line 2 (this wasn't posted in your example, though). Try adding the indentation back again and you'll see that it works.